# Как изменить содержимое переменной?

Tags: laravel

Как изменить содержимое этой переменной? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам потребовалось ее менять в шаблоне? Какова исходная задача? Суть вывода переменных в шаблоне - просто подстановка уже подготовленных данных, которые определялись ранее и затем были переданы в шаблон. Соответственно, если хотите менять - лучше менять там, где вы ее определяли (вероятно, в экшене?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ $slot }}  //начальное значение  
<?php $slot = SOME_VALUE ?>
{{ $slot }} //конечное значения SOME_VALUE
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-set-a-variable-in-blade-laravel-53. Можно использовать секцию `@php`